# Bokeh share variables between multiple callbacks

Tags: javascript, java, python, bokeh

Using Bokeh, I'd like to use six checkboxgroups to do selection and use a button widget to filter data based on the result of the selection. Eventually I want to display a data table that show the filtered data.

My problem is how to pass the checkboxgroups' active vector from the checkboxgroup callback to the button callback. Note that all my callbacks are javascript based as I want a html file to run independently.

The code can be summarized as below. `src2`is the filtered data. I tried the code but it didnt work. Anyone can help? Thx a loooooottttttt!

```
   c1u = CustomJS(args=dict(s1=source1),code="""
     var ac1 = cb_obj.active;
        """)
    c2u = CustomJS(args=dict(s1=source1),code="""
     var ac2 = cb_obj.active;
        """)
    c3u = CustomJS(args=dict(s1=source1),code="""
     var ac3 = cb_obj.active;
        """)
    c4u = CustomJS(args=dict(s1=source1),code="""
     var ac4 = cb_obj.active;
        """)
    c5u = CustomJS(args=dict(s1=source1),code="""
     var ac5 = cb_obj.active;
        """)
    c6u = CustomJS(args=dict(s1=source1),code="""
     var ac6 = cb_obj.active;
        """)
    che1.js_on_change('active',c1u)
    che2.js_on_change('active',c2u)
    che3.js_on_change('active',c3u)
    che4.js_on_change('active',c4u)
    che5.js_on_change('active',c5u)
    che6.js_on_change('active',c6u)
    
    searching = CustomJS(args=dict(src1=src1,src2=src2,c1=che1,c2=che2,c3=che3,c4=che4,c5=che5,c6=che6), code="""
            var ac1 = c1.active;
            var ac2 = c2.active;
            var ac3 = c3.active;
            var ac4 = c4.active;
            var ac5 = c5.active;
            var ac6 = c6.active;
    
     
            if (ac4.includes(5)){
                    src2.data["平台"]="1";
                    src2.data["相应产品"]="1";
                    src2.data["是否为首推产品"]="1";
            }else if (ac5.includes(4)){
                    src2.data["平台"]="0";
                    src2.data["相应产品"]="0";
                    src2.data["是否为首推产品"]="0";
            }
            src2.change.emit();
    """)
refresh = Button(label="完成",callback=searching)
table = DataTable(source=src2, columns=table_columns2, width=400, height=280)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is still an [open issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/3674) to add support for defining "DataModel" classes that could be used for user-defined property variables. In this instance you could pass such a model to all your callbacks and they would all be able to access its properties. For now, your best optionis simply to store whatever variables you like as browser globals, e.g. `window.some_var = "foo";` which would be accessible between different callbacks.

Comment: Thx for the reply but I kinda didn't get it. Because in my case, I want to pass a datasource src3 in each checkboxgroup callback to have it update. According to your reply, should I store src3 as a window variable in each checkboxgroup callback? BTW thx again!

Comment: Reading your question again, if you only need to look at the current value of other widgets in the Button callback, you can pass all the widgets as the `args` dict to the Button callback, and then the button callback can look at their state directly. You already seem to understand how the `args` dict works from the code above, so it's not clear what your question is.

Comment: Here is example with a callback that inspects several different widget values in the callback code: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/slider.html

Comment: Thx again! but it seems no matter how i tried in my js code, the datatable still doesn't update according to my chechboxgroup results. `callbackcode = """
var ac1 = che1.active;
var ac2 = che2.active;
var ac3 = che3.active;
var ac4 = che4.active;
var ac5 = che5.active;
var ac6 = che6.active;

if (ac4.includes(5)){
        src2.data["平台"][0] = "1";
        src2.data["相应产品"][0] = "1";
        src2.data["是否为首推产品"][0] = "1";
}
if (ac5.includes(4)){
        src2.data["平台"][0] = "0" ;src2.data["相应产品"][0] = "0";
        src2.data["是否为首推产品"][0] = "0";
}
src2.change.emit();
"""`